# Most efficient query to return multiple related entities in Entity Framework Core? (1:M and M:M)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a database context in Entity Framework Core 5 with tables for Tournaments, Matches, Sets, Players, and a Set-Players junction table to associate that many-to-many relationship. The linked ERD image has details. I would like to use LINQ to query for a Tournament ID, and return all associated entities for the matching Tournament (including matches, sets, players).

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EB23.png) (Edit: Just realized I misnamed a key and element on the diagram——should be SetId and SetPlayer——though this will be obvious as soon as you look at it.)

The code-first was generated by reverse-engineering the database using the EF CLI scaffolding tool, and the navigation properties are all set correctly.

I am currently using multiple separate queries:

```
var tournament = _context.Tournaments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);
var matches = await _context.Matches.Where(r => r.TournamentId == tournamentId);
var sets = ...etc
```

This is definitely inefficient, and in SQL one could simply write a SELECT * with multiple JOINs. How can I formulate a LINQ statement to return all of the elements I need using EF Core?

I've researched and experimented a huge amount, but I'm still really struggling to figure out how this is done. Here's an attempt to get at least the first associated elements, but I'm obviously not querying the data I need.

```
 var tournament = await _context.Tournaments
            .Include(t => t.Matches)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.Sets)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.SetPlayer)
            .ThenInclude(t => t.Players)
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need there are a few options. If you need some details from the Tournament and it's related data to return to a view for example, Projection using `Select()` or Automapper's `ProjectTo()` are your best friend. Returning entities is messy and I don't recommend it, even though a good number of official examples demonstrate it. Returning entities is a trap in that it sends far more data than clients need, and even with eager loading through `Include()`, as systems evolve to introduce new relationships, they introduce performance traps as serializers start lazy loading related data that old views don't need just because the navigation property is now there. (Never went back to `.Include()` yet another related entity)  Add a related table for some new feature/screen and find that users are complaining that some unrelated search screen that hasn't been touched in months is "slow".

Projecting a tournament view model with match, set, and players:

```
var tournamentSummary = await context.Tournaments
    .Where(t => t.TournamentId == tournamentId)
    .Select(t => new TournamentSummaryViewModel
    {
        TournamentId = t.TournamentId,
        Name = t.Name,
        Matches = t.Matches.Select(m => 
           new MatchSummaryViewModel
           {
               //... Fill details from match.
               Sets = m.Sets.Select(s => 
                   new SetSummaryViewModel
                   {
                       //... Fill in details from set.
                   }).ToList()
               Players = m.MatchPlayers.Select(mp =>
                   new PlayerSummaryViewModel
                   {
                       PlayerId = mp.Player.PlayerId,
                       Name = mp.Player.Name,
                       // ...
                   }).ToList()
           }
    }).SingleAsync();
```

This can look like a lot of boilerplate to copy data across, but it can be simplified considerably with Automapper, configuring what and how to map across the related entities and chopped down to a single statement:

```
var tournamentSummary = await context.Tournaments
    .Where(t => t.TournamentId == tournamentId)
    .ProjectTo<TournamentSummaryViewModel>(TournamentToSummaryMapping.Config)()
    .SingleAsync();
```

Where TournamentToSummaryMapping is an injected wrapper for a configured Automapper Configuration.

If you need an entire Entity Graph then you have a couple options. For related data that you have navigation properties you arrange the `.Include` and `.ThenInclude` as-per Fabio's example.

If you need an unrelated set of data where you have no navigation properties then you pretty much need to load them as you outlined. When it comes to using `async`/`await` I would only recommend this for either significant read operations (complex) or very high volume operations. Thread switching for `await`ed code incurs a cost which often isn't justified for simple, fast queries.

```
var match = await context.Matches.SingleAsync(x => x.MatchId == matchId);
var sets = await context.Sets.Where(x => x.MatchId == matchId).ToListAsync();
var matchPlayers = await context.MatchPlayers.Where(x => x.MatchId == matchId).ToListAsync();
```

What you cannot do is something like:

```
var matchTask = context.Matches.SingleAsync(x => x.MatchId == matchId);
var setsTask = context.Sets.Where(x => x.MatchId == matchId).ToListAsync();
var matchPlayersTask = context.MatchPlayers.Where(x => x.MatchId == matchId).ToListAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(matchTask, setsTask, matchPlayersTask);

var match = matchTask.Result;
var sets = setsTask.Result;
var matchPlayers = matchPlayersTask.Result;
```

EF will throw a hissy attempting to parallelize on a single Context. You *can* parallelize data retrieval with EF by ensuring each task method has it's own DbContext instance, but keep in mind that any entity references returned would be out of scope of the DbContext that read them (died when the task was finished) so they cannot lazy load, and the entities cannot be guaranteed to be attachable to another DbContext without first checking that context instance for tracked entities with the same ID. Explore with extreme caution. While it may save a few seconds loading, it can cost you days in added complexity and tracking down odd, intermittent looking bugs.

Usually performance concerns can be addressed more than adequately with structuring for Projection or keeping update/insert operations more atomic so entire graphs of data aren't being updated all at once.

Answer (score 0):

If navigation properties are set:

```
var tournament = await _context.Tournament
    .Include(t => t.Matches).ThenInclude(m => m.Sets)
    .Include(t => t.Matches)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.MatchPlayers).ThenInclude(m => m.Players)
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Notice that `.Include(t => t.Matches)` called twice for every sub relation.

Actually multiple different queries executed asynchronously can be more efficient than one big query.